# CUDA Independent Instruction optimization

Tags: optimization, cuda

I need suggestions regarding optimization of my kernel and device code. I understand that CUDA documentation (and so many slides) suggest usage of large thread block sizes in order to hide memory and arithmetic latency.

My kernels and device functions are quite compute intensive. Therefore I try to use as many registers as possible and (obviously) because of this I compromise on occupancy. Point is, for my application, Instruction Level Parallelism is more important than large thread blocks.

But the basic idea behind ILP is to have independent instructions. My question is

1) How to achieve this? In computation, there are always variables that are reused for other calculations.
2) Can anyone suggest or provide some examples where dependent instructions can be transformed into independent instructions?
3) I also read (somewhere) that for arithmetic computation, maximum ILP = 4 can be achieved i.e. a thread computes 4 independent instructions. Does that mean, if there exists such four instructions and after this there are dependent instructions, warp will go into waiting, until dependencies are met?
4) Can anyone suggest some reading material and code where ILP is exploited?

I present here also some code for analysis; it might not mean anything. The code represents following equation:

[Formula](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5CLARGE%20%5Cleft%20%28%20%5Cprod_%7Bi%20%3D%201%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20I%20_%7Bi%7D%20%5Cright%20%29%20%5Csum_%7Bj%20%3D%201%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Cfrac%7BSe%5E%7B-NSx%7D%5B%20N%28I_%7Bj%7D%20+%20Sx%29%20+%201%29%20%5D%7D%7B%28I_%7Bj%7D%20+%20Sx%29%5E%7B2%7D%20%5B%20%5Cprod_%7Bk%20%3D%201%2C%20k%20%5Cneq%20j%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%28I_%7Bk%7D%20-%20I_%7Bj%7D%29%5D%20%7D)

The point is I want to achieve maximum performance; and I want to use ILP for that. I have other device functions as well in my code; so I am using

Thread block:     192
14 SM (32 cores): 448 (cores)
Each SM uses 8 blocks concurrently: 8 x 192 : 1536
When compiling the code with **"-ptxas-options=-v"**  I get 50 registers per thread (occupancy somewhere around 33%)

All parameters used in the equation are type double (other than n)
e.g. n = 2. params array contains S at param[0] and I1 at param[1] and I2 at param[2]

```
#define N 3.175e-3
__device__ double gpu_f_different_mean(double x, double params[], int n) {

   double S = params[0];
   double product_I = 1.0;

   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      product_I = product_I * params[i];
   }

   double tmp   = S * exp(-N * S * x);
   double outer = product_I * tmp;

   double result = 0.0;

   for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) {

      double reduction = (params[i] + S * x);
      double numerator = 1 + N * reduction;

      double denom_prod = 1.0;
      for (int j = 1; j<= n; j++) {
         if ( i != j)
            denom_prod = denom_prod * (params[j] - params[i]);
      }

      double denominator = pow(reduction, 2) * denom_prod;
      result             = result + (numerator / denominator);
   }

   return outer * result;
}
```

## Hardware

I am using Fermi Architecture GPU GTX470, compute capability 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several comments:

a) Dependency chains like the one caused by continuous updating of `denom_prod` can be broken by introducing multiple reduction variables:

```
  double denom_prod1 = 1.0;
  double denom_prod2 = 1.0;
  int j;
  for (j = 1; j <= n-1; j += 2) {
     if ( i != j)
        denom_prod1 *= (params[j  ] - params[i]);
     if ( i != j+1)
        denom_prod2 *= (params[j+1] - params[i]);
  }
  if (j < n) {
     if ( i != j)
        denom_prod1 = denom_prod * (params[j  ] - params[i]);
  }
  double denom_prod = denom_prod1 * denom_prod2;
```

b) The conditional inside the loop can be eliminated by breaking the loop into two parts:

```
  double denom_prod = 1.0;
  for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
     denom_prod = denom_prod * (params[j] - params[i]);
  for (int j = i+1; j <= n; j++)
     denom_prod = denom_prod * (params[j] - params[i]);
```

c) You can exploit the fact that exchanging `i` and `j` will not change `denom_prod` by computing the results for (i, j) and (j, i) in one go.

d) `reduction * reduction` is faster (and potentially more accurate) than `pow(reduction, 2)`

---

Regarding your questions:

1) and 2) see my comment a).

3) This likely referred to the fact that Fermi-generation GPUs (compute capability 2.x) have two independent warp schedulers per SM, each capable of issuing two instructions per cycle, for a total of up to four instructions per cycle.

However the problem of dependent instructions reaches further than that, as dependent instructions suffer from a latency of ~16..24 cycles. I.e. the second of two dependent instructions has to wait for that many cycles before it can be issued. The cycles in between can either be used by independent instructions from the same warp (which have to be located in between the dependent instructions, as current Nvidia GPUs cannot issue instructions out-of-order). Or they can be used by instructions from other warps, which are always independent. So for optimal performance, you want either many warps, or consecutive independent instructions, or ideally both.

4) The publications of Vasily Volkov make for excellent reading on this subject, particularly his ["Better Performance at Lower Occupancy"](http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC-2010/pdfs/2238_GTC2010.pdf) presentation.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I want to dig a little bit deeper, understand about what you mean when you described _"So for optimal performance, you want either many warps, or consecutive independent instructions, or ideally both."_ 

I have already been through the presentation that you linked here, it also describes how independent instructions can increase performance, but says nothing about code transformation. 

By "So for optimal performance, you want either many warps ..." your direct reference is towards a **Large thread block size**, Is it?

Comment: I am referring to occupancy, as it does not matter whether the warps come from the same block or from other blocks. Use the [Occupancy Calculator](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) to find out how many warps are active per SM at the same time. Have you read the "CUDA C Best Practices Guide" that comes with the CUDA Toolkit, particularly chapter 7?